# create a clickonce package on local machine from Azure pipeline?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, clickonce

I am tasks with adding steps to a pipeline that will create and deploy a clickonce application from an application. Here is what I have so far for my yml file:

```
trigger:
- ReleaseCandidate

pool:
  name: 'PoolTest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'CTVdbNG.Master/NuGet.config'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/target:publish /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

I only build and test...but how do I create a clickonce package?

Answer (score 0):

> create a clickonce package on local machine from Azure pipeline?

There is no directly way or argument to generate the package for the clickonce project.

To generate the package, you could edit the project file for your client project and add the following at the bottom (right above the  tag):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--Unless specified otherwise, the tools will go to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\1 to get the installpath for msdeploy.exe.-->
    <MSDeployPath Condition="'$(MSDeployPath)'==''">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\3@InstallPath)</MSDeployPath>
    <MSDeployPath Condition="'$(MSDeployPath)'==''">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\2@InstallPath)</MSDeployPath>
    <MSDeployPath Condition="'$(MSDeployPath)'==''">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\1@InstallPath)</MSDeployPath>
    <MSDeployExe Condition=" '$(MSDeployExe)'=='' ">$(MSDeployPath)msdeploy.exe</MSDeployExe>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CreateWebDeployPackage" AfterTargets="Publish" DependsOnTargets="Publish">
    <!--
    %msdeploy% 
      -verb:sync 
      -source:contentPath="C:\Temp\_NET\WebPackageWithClickOnce\WebPackageWithClickOnce\bin\Debug\app.publish" 
      -dest:package="C:\Temp\_NET\WebPackageWithClickOnce\WebPackageWithClickOnce\bin\Debug\co-pkg.zip"
      -->
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Cmd>"$(MSDeployExe)" -verb:sync -source:contentPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(PublishDir)" -dest:package="$(OutDir)cotest.zip"</Cmd>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Message Text="Creating web deploy package with command: $(Cmd)" />
    <Exec Command="$(Cmd)" />
  </Target>
```

It will generate the `cotest.zip` under the path `bin\Debug\cotest.zip`.

Source reference: [Create a clickonce webdeploy package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292986/create-a-clickonce-webdeploy-package)